# Ten days have passed TO/OF/FOR some event

Tags: prepositions

I am writing a line, but confused using a preposition:

> Almost ten days have passed ***to/of/for*** Apple’s WWDC 2015 event.

This is just an example. What it takes when we talk about 'X number of days have passed to/of/for any event?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A couple good options: *since*, and nothing.

Comment: @DamkerngT. How we can write above sentence by using 'nothing'?

Comment: The pattern I thought of was *X days passed (or have passed) the deadline*, which is a variant of *The deadline has passed; It's (has) already passed the deadline; It's (is) past the deadline.* Though I still think that *Almost X days have passed event Y* is possible, now I think that using *since* (or even *after*) in your sentence is much safer.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I"m afraid *have passed event Y* won't work. You may be thinking of *It is now ten days **past** event Y*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word you're looking for is *since*.

Almost ten days have passed ***since*** Apple’s WWDC 2015 event.

Comment: What if I use any of mentioned prepositions? Will any of these preposition make my sentence wrong?  'Since' looks the best option, but can I write the sentence by using any of above proposition?

Comment: none of the others work - since is the only good option.

Comment: `of` could be used if you're trying to say something along the lines of "Apple's WWDC 2015 event is in progress. Ten days of the event have passed", or in other words "Almost 10 days **of** Apple's WWDC 2015 event have passed". To my thinking, saying "Almost ten days have passed since Apple’s WWDC 2015 event" means "Apple's WWDC 2015 event ended almost ten days ago".

Answer (score 3):

"Of" works if the event is ongoing. If the conference were fifteen days long, you could say that "ten days have passed of the conference" meaning that five of them are still remaining.

It's not exactly the construction you quote, but you can use "to" before the event: "It was still ten days to the conference" but "until" works better there.

"From" could work either before or after the event, but probably better before than after.